# How to convert String to function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following code which I am using for making a simple template engine.The html page is as follows:-

```
<ns tmp="red"></ns>
<ns tmp="blue"></ns>
```

On the other hand I have a JavaScript as in a JQuery Plugin which reads the tags and then gets the attribute of `tmp`
now I want to receive the value of the string and then convert it to a function so as to give a call to a predefined value inside the object but the conversion of the string to function is not working. I referred some questions in Stack overflow but wasn't useful. Then JQuery code I have mentioned below.

```
(function($){

    /*Collection of the template data*/
    var k=template();
    /*This retrieves all the custom tags and gets the template
    property to point to.*/
    var templateArray=$('ns');
    templateArray.each(function(){
    var template=$(this).attr('tmp');
    var funcName=window[template]();//This does not work
    alert(l());
    });
})(jQuery);

    function template(){
        var t={
            blue:function(){
            return "Hello";
            },
             red:function(){
            return "ff";
            }
        };
        return t;
    }
```

Please suggest how to get along this. I have this on fiddle too. feel free to edit so that I would be able to call the function inside the object in some way.Thanks
Fiddle Link [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/shivkumarganesh/YS9Gs/)

Comment: You're calling `window["red"]` and `window["blue"];` but there are no methods defined on the window that are named red and blue.

Comment: So you actually want to call k[template], not window[template], right?

Comment: @David consider I want to get the function or convert the string to the function and call it like k.MyFunction() . Rather than attaching it to the window is there any other way from where I can use the object k to call the function within it ie. blue

Comment: @Mikhail is correct, here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9Gs/3/) proving this..

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov ya something like k.[template] where [template] refers to the function I get after conversion of string to function.Hope I am clear, if not please let me know.

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you explain how this actually works or what is the name of such concept? So that i could understand better. as in k[template] . This works fine and is looking great. please provide me details.

Comment: Instead of using a function to store your template functions you can use an array. http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/YS9Gs/6/ In JavaScript objects and arrays are the same so `template_functions.red` is the same as `template_functions['red']`

Comment: @Thomas Sounds good Thomas. I am trying to make a simple template engine I guess JSON data would be good to get along with right. In such conditions?

Comment: you can use eval(template)(); ------------------------------------------------
Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because: body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript objects and arrays are the same thing. So `template.red` and `template['red']` are the same thing.

I suggest putting the functions into an array. This way you can even extend it at run time.

http://jsfiddle.net/tricki/YS9Gs/10/

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for about objects and arrays. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

As also pointed out in a comment, the functions you want to execute are not part of the `window` object but rather part of your `template` object, thus you need to take them from the proper place.

Also, using the same name of existing function for a local variable might work, but not a good idea at all, you better use proper names.

Working code:

```
templateArray.each(function(){
    var tmp = $(this).attr('tmp');
    var funcName=k[tmp];
    var result = funcName();
    alert(result);
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YS9Gs/3/).